# Error reading file share paths as arguments

Tags: powershell

I am receiving the following error when I execute the below script.

> Test-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument 'input.dat'.

```
.\FL.ps1 \\flamingdev\analytics\source\INBOUND   \\flamingdev\analytics\source\OUTBOUND

[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [string] $SrcFolder,
  [string] $FileListPath
)

$SrcFolder
$FileListPath

IF (Test-Path "$FileListPath"\input.dat) {
Remove-Item "$FileListPath"\input.dat
}

Get-ChildItem -File -Path "$SrcFolder"\Extract* | Select-Object - ExpandProperty Name | Add-Content -Path "$FileListPath"\input.dat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meed to take "all path" in double quotes. Like this:

```
IF (Test-Path "$FileListPath\input.dat") {
Remove-Item "$FileListPath\input.dat"
}
 Get-ChildItem -File -Path "$SrcFolder\Extract*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Add-Content -Path "$FileListPath\input.dat"
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes I tried that as well and I get the following error. "Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name."

Comment: Did you call cmndlet that way?:     .\FL.ps1 "\\flamingdev\analytics\source\INBOUND" "\\flamingdev\analytics\source\OUTBOUND"

Comment: And this is another error than 1st one (as you asked): Test-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'input.dat'.   Can you give a full error log here?

Comment: Thank you, issue was resolved after tweaking the code little bit. Get-ChildItem -File -Path "$SrcFolder","*.csv"

Comment: You are welcome. Mark my post as an answer if it helps you.  have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, issue was resolved after tweaking the code little bit. Get-ChildItem -File -Path "$SrcFolder","*.csv"